# Apache serves Subdomain instead of Domain

Tags: virtualhost, apache2, subdomain

I had two sites up and running on my server(`nextcloud.example.com`(Nextcloud Instance) & `example.com` (Grav Instance)). I added a Postfix configuration on the server and now I'm also able to send mails. But I messed something up with my certificates, so I redid them...

The **main Problem** now is that, always when I'm trying to open `example.com` it's always calling `example.com/index.php/login` which renders the LogIn page from `nextcloud.example.com` but I'm expecting my Grav main page. also when I'm calling `example.com/admin` it resolves to `example.com/index.php/login`.

I'm pretty new in this topic so I'm hoping this will be the relevant Data:

```
$ apachectl configtest
Syntax OK
```

**I did inserted my conf-files here, but StackExchange marked my Text-Area to be spam. So I removed them**. I'm Happy to provide you with more Information, I just wasn't allowed...

**EDIT:**

```
apache2ctl -S
VirtualHost configuration:
127.0.1.1:443          example.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/example.com-le-ssl.conf:2)
127.0.1.1:80           example.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/example.com.conf:1)
5.252.225.176:443      nextcloud.example.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/nextcloud.example.com-le-ssl.conf:2)
5.252.225.176:80       nextcloud.example.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/nextcloud.example.com.conf:1)
ServerRoot: "/etc/apache2"
Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www/html"
Main ErrorLog: "/var/log/apache2/error.log"
Mutex rewrite-map: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-stapling-refresh: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-stapling: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-cache: using_defaults
Mutex default: dir="/var/run/apache2/" mechanism=default 
Mutex mpm-accept: using_defaults
Mutex watchdog-callback: using_defaults
PidFile: "/var/run/apache2/apache2.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="www-data" id=33 not_used
Group: name="www-data" id=33 not_used
```

```
<VirtualHost nextcloud.example.com:443>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/nextcloud.example.com/htdocs/
  ServerName  nextcloud.example.com

  <Directory /var/www/nextcloud.example.com/htdocs/>
    Require all granted
    AllowOverride All
    Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews

    <IfModule mod_dav.c>
      Dav off
    </IfModule>
  </Directory>
RewriteEngine off
# Some rewrite rules in this file were disabled on your HTTPS site,
# because they have the potential to create redirection loops.

#RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =nextcloud.example.com
#RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]

SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost example.com:443>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/htdocs/
  ServerName  example.com

  <Directory /var/www/example.com/htdocs/>
    Require all granted
    AllowOverride All
    Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews

    <IfModule mod_dav.c>
      Dav off
    </IfModule>
  </Directory>
RewriteEngine on
# Some rewrite rules in this file were disabled on your HTTPS site,
# because they have the potential to create redirection loops.

#RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =example.com
#RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]

SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: We need to see your Apache config, at least the virtual hosts, in order to answer your question. Maybe try to post them again? Also, are you really running Apache 2.2?

Comment: I've added the conf files, seems to be working with the edit :) And I changed the tag to apache2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to change the hostnames in your VirtualHost directives to `*`. That is, instead of

```
<VirtualHost nextcloud.example.com:443>
  ServerName  nextcloud.example.com
  ...
</VirtualHost>
<Virtualhost example.com:443>
  ServerName  example.com
  ...
</VirtualHost>
```

try

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName  nextcloud.example.com
  ...
</VirtualHost>
<Virtualhost *:443>
  ServerName  example.com
  ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Generally the argument of VirtualHost should be an IP address, or `*` to match all IP addresses.

The first form above will fail if the IP address where Apache receives the connection is different from the DNS address of example.com - for example, if example.com is behind a proxy. In that case, Apache will fall back to serving from the default virtual host, which is the first one, which in your case appears to be nextcloud.example.com.

See [VirtualHost](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#virtualhost), and [Name-based virtual hosts](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/name-based.html).

Comment: I updated the vhosts entries and restarted the the server. Works like a charme! Thanks a lot!